# appending field at the begining of data in text file with perl

Tags: perl

I have source file data like below

01ADA
02U523919   ff
03U523919   jj
04U523919   kk
01NNA
06U12222    aa
07U88888    bb
08U99999    cc

Based on O1ADA or O1NNA, I need to append this data and create output file as below

01ADA 02U523919   ff
01ADA 03U523919   jj
01ADA 04U523919   kk
01NNA 06U12222    aa
01NNA 07U88888    bb
01NNA 08U99999    cc

How can i do it with perl or awk
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This may be more easy to understand. Put your file content into the file named test_file.

```
  1 #!/usr/bin/perl
  2 use utf8;
  3 use strict;
  4 use warnings;
  5
  6 sub write_in_special_pattern {
  7     open my $file_handler, '<', 'test_file' or die;
  8     open my $new_handler, '>', 'write_test' or die;
  9     my $sign;
 10     while (my $row = <$file_handler>) {
 11         if ($row =~/01ADA/) {
 12             $sign = '01ADA';
 13             next;
 14         } elsif ($row =~ /01NNA/){
 15             $sign = '01NNA';
 16             next;
 17         }
 18         print $new_handler $sign.' '.$row;
 19     }
 20     close $file_handler;
 21     close $new_handler;
 22 }
 23
 24 write_in_special_pattern();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jack. Really appreciate it

Comment: you are welcome. It's my pleasure that it can give some help to you.